# Counting values matched in an array

Tags: c#

Ok so, I am looking through a document for certain values, and if they match the values in this array, then I want to increase the count for that specific value.  I did this:

```
public static class Hex
{
    //example only, not real code
    public static string[] name = {"aba", "bcd", "c"}; 

    public static int[] count = new int[name.Length];
}
```

But it seems like there must be a better/easier way.  Maybe an array of tuple?  I just don't know.  I know its a pretty easy question, I just can't think of quite how to do it with both strings to compare in 1, and int count for them.  Thanks!

Comment: Show us what did you try.

Comment: @CMate This is exactly what I tried.  It works fine.  I just think there is probably a better way to do it that is more... classic.  This must come up all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `Dictionary<string, int>` since it is very efficient:

```
public static class Hex
{
    static Hex()
    {
        _HexNameCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>() 
        {
            {"aba", 0}, {"bcd", 0}, {"c", 0}
        };

    }

    private static Dictionary<string, int> _HexNameCounts = null;

    public static int? GetHexNameCount(string name)
    {
        int count;
        if (_HexNameCounts.TryGetValue(name, out count))
            return count;
        return null;
    }

    public static void SetHexNameCount(string name, int count)
    {
        _HexNameCounts[name] = count;
    }

    public static void IncreaseHexNameCount(string name, int count = 1)
    {
        int c = GetHexNameCount(name) ?? 0;
        SetHexNameCount(name, c + count);
    }
}
```

Now you can use it in this way:

```
int? abaCount = Hex.GetHexNameCount("aba");  
// or
Hex.SetHexNameCount("c", 3);  
// or
Hex.IncreaseHexNameCount("foo", 10);
```

It's always good to encapsulate complexity in methods. That makes the code more readable and safer.

I have used a `Nullable<int>` to handle the case that the name is new.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to return `0` from `GetHexNameCount()`, rather than `null`?  It's getting the count, after all.  Plus, you wouldn't need to use the null-coalescing operator in `IncreaseHexNameCount()` either.

Comment: @JohnH: Why? It provides the opportunity to differentiate between a name that is yet  not available and a name which count is actually zero.

Comment: Because the name `GetHexNameCount` implies it's getting the count of something.  If you don't have any of something, the count is `0`, not `null`.

Comment: @JohnH: What is the benefit  of that? The result of `GetHexNameCount("aba")` and `GetHexNameCount("Foo")` would be the same even if the former has a valid count of 0 and the latter has no count at all. My approach returns simply more informations.

Comment: I get where you're coming from, but I don't see how that information is actually helping anything.  I wouldn't expect a method that's saying it will get the count of anything to be able to return `null`.  You could also argue that it's not that method's responsibility to determine whether or not an element exists in that dictionary.  Either way, I'm happy to agree to disagree.

Comment: With the same argument you could ask why a database returns `null` even if you clearly ask for a scalar `int` value like here: `SELECT TOP 1 count FROM T WHERE Name='NotAvailable'`. Why does it return `NULL` instead of `0`? Because it's important to know that the name is not available and this information is for free. So you're also free to ignore it.

Comment: Also, the return type of a method can help to understand the method itself. So if a method returns a `Nullable<T>` i know that it can be null which means that the value i've provided was not available. If it would return `int` instead i wouldn't know if it return `0`, `-1` or `int.MinValue` or even throw an exception if the name was new. So the type also increases readability.

Answer (score 1):

use [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dictionary.Add("aba", 0);
dictionary.Add("bcd", 0);
dictionary.Add("c", 0);
```

Later you can search for the word in `Dictionary.Keys` and increment the counter.

Comment: Any way to add a bunch of values at once?  I have 28 values to add!

Answer (score 1):

What about a `Dictionary<string, int>`?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<string, int> matches = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach(var item in document)
{
    if(matches.ContainsKey(item.stringvalue))
    {
       matches[item.stringvalue] += 1;
    }
    else
    {
       matches.Add(item.stringvalue, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary as bellow:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dicObj = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dicObj.Add("abc", 0);
…
```

After that you can search for the particular word in this using `dicObj.ContainsKey` and you can perform your business logic.